# Is this question even correct?

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

Suppose that $X$ is a topological space which is path-connected. Let $x_0∈ X$. Show that the function $ t_{x_0} : {X} \to {X×X}$  where $t_{x_0}(x)=(x,x_0)$ is an embedding and image of $X$ under $t_{x_0}$ is closed in ${X×X}$.

I know it is trivial that $X$ and its image are homeomorphic. My question is why $X$ need to be path-connected in order to show what the question requires. Is this related  to the image of $X$ being closed under $t_{x_0}$?

I really appreciate if someone could explain why path-connectivity is required!

Comment: Being "path connected" is irrelevant. Your $t_{x_0}$ is always a homeomorphism onto image. Moreover the image of $X$ does not have to be closed in $X\times X$, even when it is path connected (for example the antidiscrete topology). This works when $\{x_0\}$ is closed in $X$ (in particular when $X$ is $T_1$) but not otherwise. Whoever gave you this problem probably meant $X$ to be $T_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection map $p_2\colon X\times X\rightarrow X,(x_1,x_2)\mapsto x_2$ is continuous by definition of the product topology, therefore preimages of closed subsets are closed. If for $x_0\in X$ the singelton subset $\{x_0\}\subset X$ is closed, then $t_{x_0}(X)=X\times\{x_0\}=p_2^{-1}(\{x_0\})\subset X\times X$ is closed. As you can see, the condition of path-connectedness is irrelevant, only that $\{x_0\}$ is closed. The alternative condition of $X$ being a $T_1$ space would guarantee this.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you. Thanks for your answer. Actually this is a lemma for using its extension to build topologies on $X^n$ in which for each i < j,  $Xi$ is a subspace of $Xj$. For example we can build topologies on $R^n$ for any n with extending this lemma, and consequently a topology on R infinity with some more effort.

Comment: Sounds interesting, where can I find this lemma?

Comment: I searched and I couldn't find it on the web, It's in my notes. By the way if I could find it on the web, then probably I wouldn't need to ask about it here!

Comment: Ah, so the question was for this lemma. Then my question was indeed a bit stupid.